# Close window while in alt tab

Tags: windows-7

In windows 7, when you press alt tab you get a list of windows and can cycle through them effectively. Is there a way to close the window you are currently on instead of actually going to that window and pressing the "x" or alt f4.

Comment: There isn't a way to close the processes while in that view.

Comment: There are some custom made alt-tabs replacing tools out there though.

Comment: For those who find this question looking for Windows 10 functionality, alt-tabbing to the desired app, holding alt, and pressing Delete, closes the window.

Answer (score 12):

1. Open the persistent Alt+Tab menu with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.
2. Select the window with arrow keys or tab keys (<kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>).
3. Close the selected window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>. This will work even for applications that do not natively support Ctrl+W.

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit the Alt+Tab menu.

Comment: I did not know about the persistent alt+tab menu. Thank you.

Comment: You could also old on the Alt key releasing the Tab while Alt+Tab instead of the persistent menu then step 2 et 3 still working

Answer (score 10):

Alt+tab to the window you need to close. Holding alt press "Enter", it will focus selected window, then press F4 on the same alt. The most programs support "Alt+F4" as a way for quiting them. Don't release alt and you'll can keep on alt+tabbing.

So, MacOS can **command**+(tab→q→tab→q→tab→q...)

In Win7 **alt**+(tab→enter→f4→tab→enter→f4→tab→enter→f4→...) works fine for me.

And don't forget, you can use arrows to navigate through alttab context menu.

Comment: Your sequence does not work for me in  Win 7.... Wondering why?

Comment: Let me guess, Arrows doesn't work too?
If simplified classic theme is chosen in the personalisation menu - sad, but true the method won't work.

Comment: Excellent !..... I changed to Aero themes and now It works...... Cool stuff

Answer (score 4):

For the Windows 10 users out there, while you could use the persistent menu, see [anishpatel's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1231094/738030), you can save your self a single key press with:

<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> to the app you want to close and press <kbd>delete</kbd>

- additionally, if you continue holding <kbd>alt</kbd> you can close multiple apps

Comment: This solution is really nice if you don't know in advance that you will want to close multiple windows while triggerring the Alt+Tab shortcut. Require two hands but perfect.